# wordpress woocommerce remove widget on specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, https, widget, woocommerce

I've got a widget on the WooCommerce checkout page which breaks the https encryption (it makes a http call and therefore the browser throws a security warning).

Therefore I would like to disable the widget only on the checkout page.

There are plugins which could solve this, but I'd rather not install further plugins for something I possibly could solve easily by adding some code to the functions.php. But it seems impossible for me to find a working solution.

For instance this code disables the plugin on all pages:

```
add_action('widgets_init', 'unregWS', 11);
function unregWS() {
    unregister_widget('Woo_Widget_Subscribe');
}
```

And this code does not seem to recognize that there is a checkout page

```
add_action('widgets_init', 'unregWS', 11);
function unregWS() {
    if(is_checkout()){
        unregister_widget('Woo_Widget_Subscribe');
    }
}
```

I've also tried is_page() and get_page_ID() to specify the page where the widget needs to be disabled. All of those functions seem not to work when initializing the widgets through widgets_init.

Does anyone see an easy solution here?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/ study this plugin and add the code into your function.php simple :p

Comment: I don't think the query object (needed for `is_page()`, etc logic) is set up yet by the `widgets_init` hook. The easy solution is to just use one of the many plugins that can conditionally load widgets. This isn't a theme/appearance-specific issue anyway so the code doesn't really belong in functions.php as I'd assume you'd want this to work even if you ever changed your theme.

Comment: @manoj dhiman: I've already tried. The reason I'm asking here is because I'm not smart enough to figure it out by reading the code. A short working example would be of much help.